# Translate TAB with C-q TAB

Tags: keymap, tab-key

I'm an amateur in Emacs and I would like to change `TAB` with `C-q TAB`. I used the code:

`(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "TAB") (kbd"C-q TAB"))`

But by doing so, I need to press `TAB` twice in order to get a indent and under the screen it shows `C-q TAB TAB`.

Why would this happen? How can I get the indent only by pressing `TAB` once?

Comment: What is it that you are *really* trying to do? If you want `TAB` to just insert a `TAB` character then bind `TAB` to `self-insert-command`. But be aware that various modes bind `TAB` in other ways, so you may need to either bind it to what you want in those modes or define a minor mode where you bind it to what you want, and then turn on that minor mode.

Comment: @Drew that's what I want. Can you tell me how to achieve it exactly?

Comment: Then the answer you want is [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/27943/105). And really this question should probably be closed as a duplicate of that one (or nearly duplicate - at least that answer is what you're looking for).