# Where does my key bind so I can unbind it in major mode

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode

I changed my key bindings with this lines in my `.init.d`:

`(global-set-key "\C-i" 'previous-line)`

It works normally, but when I change to `markdown-mode`, key rebinds to something else, how can I disable that binding and keep this original one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Avoiding overwriting global key bindings](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/avoiding-overwriting-global-key-bindings)

Answer (score 2):

Markdown has defined the key `C-i` in it's own keymap. This keymap is named `markdown-mode-map`.
Markdown's mode-map has a higher priority than your global binding and therefore it shadows you global binding.
You can verify this, by pressing `C-h k C-i` in markdown-mode.

If you want your global keybinding not shadowed, then you have to remove the keybinding from Markdowns's mode-map. You do that by setting the value `nil` to that keybinding:

```
(define-key markdown-mode-map (kbd "C-i") nil)
```