# Stop major modes from overwriting my keybinding

Tags: key-bindings, major-mode, prefix-keys

By default `C-x n` is a [prefix keymap](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Prefix-Keymaps.html) used for [narrowing](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Narrowing.html).

I want to bind `C-x n` to `windmove-down`.

```lisp
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x n") 'windmove-down)
```

This works fine for Text mode. But many major modes seem to overwrite these bindings:

- [Markdown mode](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/blob/master/markdown-mode.el):

  - C-x n b → markdown-narrow-to-block
  - C-x n s → markdown-narrow-to-subtree
- Orgmode:

  - C-x n b → org-narrow-to-block
  - C-x n e → org-narrow-to-element
  - C-x n s → org-narrow-to-subtree

So I would like to know: How can I stop all (major) modes from overwriting my binding?

Comment: Or this: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27926/avoiding-overwriting-global-key-bindings

Comment: I also *highly* recommend reading https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs in order to understand how keymap precedence works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should steal the technique used by [`bind-key*`](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package/blob/master/bind-key.el).

Basically, the bindings in minor modes take precedence over major modes, and minor modes in the `emulation-mode-map-alists` take über precedence. Mastering Emacs has a [good outline of keymap lookup order](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/mastering-key-bindings-emacs#keymap-lookup-order).

Here's a sampling from my config:

```
(defvar my/keys-keymap (make-keymap)
  "Keymap for my/keys-mode")

(define-minor-mode my/keys-mode
  "Minor mode for my personal keybindings."
  :init-value t
  :global t
  :keymap my/keys-keymap)

;; The keymaps in `emulation-mode-map-alists' take precedence over
;; `minor-mode-map-alist'
(add-to-list 'emulation-mode-map-alists
             `((my/keys-mode . ,my/keys-keymap)))

(define-key my/keys-keymap (kbd "M-o") 'other-window)
```

Comment: Worked wonderfully and even feels somewhat cleaner then just globaly defining multiple related keybindings one by one. Thank you.

Comment: I tried this approach and somehow it never worked for me; I think there's something with `use-package` and hyperbole's loading process. What worked for me was https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/75075/19526.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs has no mechanism to prevent this other than convention. The convention is that all of the alphabetical keys starting with `C-c` are reserved for the user. You could change your key binding to `C-c n` and it wouldn’t be overwritten.

The other alternative is to configure hook functions in your init file so that when a buffer enters a mode that shadows your `C-x n` binding, your hook function resets your keybinding in the mode’s local keymap. However, this probably means writing a different hook function for every mode.